# PHP - MySQL - for Loop not behaving

Tags: php, mysql

Could anyone explain to me why the first DBcall function returns values, but the 2nd one does not...?

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 18 ; $i++) { 
   echo $sql = 'SELECT a FROM table_a WHERE id ="'.$a[$i].'"'; 
   echo "<br>";
   $g = dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname,$sql)[0];
   echo $g."<br>";
   echo $sql = 'SELECT bFROM table_b WHERE id ="'.$a[$i].'"'; 
   echo "<br>";
   $h = dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname,$sql)[0];
   echo $h ."<br>";
}
```

`

Heres the function:

```
  function dbCall($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $sql) {
                $item = [];
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

                } 

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                // output data of each row
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                        $item[] = $row[0];
                    }
                } else {
                    $item[] = "0 results";
                }
                $conn->close();
                return $item;
            }
```

`

And the results:

> `SELECT a FROM table_a WHERE id ="1234567"`
>   
> 72
>   `SELECT b FROM table_b WHERE id ="1234567"`
>   
>   0 results

Shouldn't they return theri respective values?

I'm

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: queries inside of loop = almost always wrong

Comment: Thanks guys,
With that being said.
Whats a better good practice method of adjusting what I need done?

Comment: @nogad Queries inside a loop, each of which creates its own MySQL connection is unquestionably wrong.

Comment: I don't know where you're learning from but it looks like you're pretty much lost in the weeds here. Is this a small part of a bigger project? If it is you'd be better off investing a little time in finding a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that fits your style and needs as it will offer many examples of how to do this properly. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is particularly beginner friendly and there are [many tutorials](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-1/) that walk you through the basics.

Comment: hi @tadman , yea I'm just learning stuff on the side, most of this stuff is just me trying to understand this stuff.

that being said, how come it doesn't return the value like it does the first time?

Comment: In the second query, there should be a space before FROM : SELECT b FROM table_b

Comment: I get where you're coming from, I'm just trying to steer you in the right direction. We all had to start somewhere! When programming be extra observant, a single character can take hours to track down if you've made a subtle mistake. `bFROM` is one such example.

Comment: Thanks! @vincenth I tried it with the space adjusted. but I'm still getting the same result?

Comment: Could you use mysqli_error after your query and post the error message if any ?

Comment: @vincenth Where would I put the SQLi error? And even if there was...shouldn't it automatically fail? As per my first if statement in the function? Its not that its failing, its just not giving the me what the contents of the query...

Comment: @vincenth - I put in the error and it doesn't return anything :(

Comment: That might seem like a stupid question, but are you sure that table_b contains data. If it does, are you sure that it contains a row whose id is what your looking for ?

Comment: @vincenth Yes I'm sure, and I just figured out why like tadman said.. seems like ther was a special character in the datas that returned.

I put in `trim($a[$i])`,and everything worked.